# View in django launched twice

Tags: python, django, view

All my views in Django are launched twice each time I'm calling them with a URL.

Here is one example:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'), # Notice the URL has been named
    url(r'login/', views.login, name='test'), # Notice the URL has been named
    url(r'login_click/', 'polls.views.login_click', name='login_click'),

    url(r'^profiler1_click/', views.profiler1, name='profiler1'),

]
```

views.py

```
def login (request):
    print("testpagelogin")
    return render(request, "login.html", {})
```

The print("testloginpage") is printed twice and I don't understand why.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should end the first url with $

example: url(r'login/$', views.login, name='test').

So a url request such as localhost:8000/login calls only views.login

Answer (score 0):

Need to include `$` at the end of url pattern
i.e. : `url(r'login/$', views.login, name='test')`